# Square of Cauchy sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Please help find an example to prove that the convergence of  ${a_n^2}$ does not imply the convergence of $a_n$, where both are sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$.